# joomla- How to remove unwanted js files from page

Tags: php, joomla

joomla- How to remove unwanted js files from page

I have used plugins some pages so many js files are included in all pages

Comment: If a javascript file is needed by a plugin, you may run into trouble if you remove it. Wouldn't it be better to remove the plugin itself? This should also remove the javascript file.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

There are two ways that I am aware of:

1) get an instance if the document object and remove the js files (you could do that in a plugin) :

```
<?php 
         //get the array containing all the script declarations
         $document = JFactory::getDocument(); 
         $headData = $document->getHeadData();
         $scripts = $headData['scripts'];

         //remove your script, i.e. mootools
         unset($scripts['/media/system/js/mootools-core.js']);
         unset($scripts['/media/system/js/mootools-more.js']);
         $headData['scripts'] = $scripts;
         $document->setHeadData($headData);
?>
```

2) remove js files directly from your templates index.php :

```
<?php unset($this->_scripts['/media/system/js/mootools-core.js']); ?>
```

Answer (score 6):

If you want to remove all scripts that Joomla adds, including the inline script, the quickest way is this:

```
$this->_script = $this->_scripts = array();
```

Add this anywhere in your template file above the `<head>` section.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply edit these plugins code to remove these files. or uninstall these plugins if not required.

Answer (score -7):

```
**An easiest way to disable mootools/ unwanted javascripts for your site in joomla cms ( 2.5 version )**(still loads it for your admin)


**Step-1:** 
Using your favorite file editor, open for edit:
libraries/joomla/document/html/renderer/head.php

**Step-2:** check for code in head.php

// Generate script file links
foreach ($document->_scripts as $strSrc => $strAttr)
{
// *** start *** //
$ex_src = explode("/",$strSrc);
$js_file_name = $ex_src[count($ex_src)-1];
$js_to_ignore = array("mootools-more.js","core.js"); // scripts to skip loading
//skip loading scripts..
if( in_array($js_file_name,$js_to_ignore) AND substr_count($document->baseurl,"/administrator") < 1 AND $_GET['view'] != 'form'){continue;}
// *** end *** //


**Step-3:** 
Clear cache & refresh page.


it works for sure.

For detailed explanation : http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/edu/joomla-25/302-disable-mootools-in-joomla-25
```

Comment: Modifying core files is not advised