# disabling mootools in joomla 3.2

Tags: joomla

How can I disable Mootools in Joomla 3.2 without hacking core files? I have already tested [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10685152/joomla-how-to-remove-unwanted-js-files-from-page), but it does not work for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple way is edit your templates not to include it but some things still require it.
http://pbwebdev.com/blog/removing-mootools-core-js-caption-js-joomla

Newer versions of 3.2.3 remove the tooltip js that was built in mootools but earlier ones will give you a console error if you have forms using it for the tip on the input label.

Also Kunena Forum uses mootools for the profiles and post edit tools, so I tend to write code that just includes it there.

Outside that there are plugins in the JED
http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/core-enhancements/performance/mootools/22236

Answer (score 0):

I found [this page on docs.joomla.org](http://docs.joomla.org/J3.2%3aJavascript_Frameworks) helpful. I was using `JHtml::_('behavior.framework')` which loads mootools.