# Joomla 3 + Bootstrap 3 - Collapsed navbar jumping when clicked

Tags: jquery, html, css, joomla, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a custom Joomla template (nothing overly complicated) and using a custom bootstrap with 15 columns (used their website to generate). Everything is working perfectly except for the collapsible navbar. I only find the problem on PCs (and only certain PCs, but they all have chrome, not mobile devices with chrome.)

Here is the link: http://www.gryphongames.co.za

How to reproduce the issue:

Load the page.
Resize the browser until the mobile navbar with the toggle button appears just below the logo.
Click on the toggle button.

What happens is the collapsed info appears but immediately jumps back to collapsed mode again. Also it is very inconsistent as it sometimes works.

Any assistance would be appreciated.

Comment: Now it seems like it is doing the same on mobile devices

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the problem:

I was including my custom bootstrap js file and jquery in my template.

The

```
<jdoc:include type="head" />
```

also included the default headers. I suspect that these duplicates were the cause. Will fix it with excluding those from the header as described here: [joomla- How to remove unwanted js files from page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10685152/joomla-how-to-remove-unwanted-js-files-from-page)